# How to resume fragment on Bottom navigation menu click?

Tags: java, bottomnavigationview

I have created bottom navigation view with 5 items. On item multiple clicks, fragments are re-created 
 and stored multiple times into the stack. I want to resume fragment if it is available in stack without poping other fragments.

MainActivity.java

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.feed:
                    String feed_tag = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_tag);
                    if(!getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(feed_tag, 0)){
                        //fragment is not in backStack, create it
                    FeedFragment f1=new FeedFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft1.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f1, feed_tag).addToBackStack(feed_tag);
                        ft1.commit();
                    }
                    return true;

                case R.id.search:
                    String search_tag = getResources().getString(R.string.search_tag);

                    if((!getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(search_tag, 0)) {
                        SearchFragment f3 = new SearchFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction ft3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft3.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f3, search_tag).addToBackStack(search_tag);
                        ft3.commit();
                    }
                    return true;

                case R.id.post:
                    String post_tag = getResources().getString(R.string.post_tag);

                    if(!getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(post_tag, 0);) {
                        Post postBase = new Post();
                        FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft2.replace(R.id.fragment_container, postBase, post_tag).addToBackStack(post_tag);
                        ft2.commit();
                    }
                    return true;

                case R.id.noti:
                    String noti_tag = getResources().getString(R.string.notification_tag);
                    if(!getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(noti_tag, 0)) {
                        NotificationFragment f4 = new NotificationFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction ft4 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft4.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f4, noti_tag).addToBackStack(noti_tag);
                        ft4.commit();
                    }
                    return true;

                case R.id.profile:
                    String profile_tag = getResources().getString(R.string.profile_tag);
                    if(!getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(profile_tag, 0)) {
                        Fragment f5 = ProfileFragment.getInstance("val1", "val2");
                        FragmentTransaction ft5 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft5.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f5, profile_tag).addToBackStack(profile_tag);
                        ft5.commit();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

If I use POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE flag, the fragment which I click get also removed and I got that fragment which is below the clicked fragment in backstack.

How can I get back already added fragment from backstack without recreating?

Comment: If you use `replace` instead of `add/hide/show`, your Fragments will be recreated no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. Without recreating :

```
val firstFragment: Fragment = FirstFragment()
val secondFragment: Fragment = SecondFragment()
val thirdFragment: Fragment = ThirdFragment()

val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

var active = firstFragment
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, thirdFragment, "3").hide(thirdFragment).commit()
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, secondFragment, "2").hide(secondFragment).commit()
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, firstFragment, "1").commit()

navView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {  }
navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
   when (item.itemId) {
       R.id.navigation_first -> {
           fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(firstFragment).commit()
           active = firstFragment

       }
       R.id.navigation_second -> {
           fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(secondFragment).commit()
           active = secondFragment
       }
       R.id.navigation_third -> {
           fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(thirdFragment).commit()
           active = thirdFragment
       }
   }
    true
 }
```

Comment: If nested fragments are open, then I can not get bottom navigation menu fragments.

Comment: If you use replace for nested fragment , yes menu item selected is not working. You should use add again for nested fragment.  for example : val nested = NestedFragment()
            activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, nested, "4").hide(active).commit()
            active = nested

Comment: How Can I manage active fragment from different file location?

Comment: Call like this (activity as YourActivity).active in any fragment. First define active to public in YourActivity

Comment: Hey, I am facing trouble with backstack on backPressed, as already added fragment is at any position in the stack. Can you please help me? @Kasım Özdemir

Comment: Hi, do you use backstack. Is this problem?

Comment: Yes, I use backstack to track backpresses.

Comment: maybe, you can use this way : val count = supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
        if (count > 0)
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(),  but don't add fragments of bottom navigation to backtack. Just add other fragments

Comment: Can you please suggest any other way to do backpressed navigation with bottomNavigation items? Because if I don't push this items on backstack, then application will exit by skipping fragments, both bottom navigation and nested. If this is the flow-(Frag1 - frag1.1 - Frag2 - Frag3 -  Frag5 - Frag5.1) and if here I pressed back then flow will be (Frag 5.1 - Frag5 - Frag1 - exit).

Comment: Also, If nested fragment is poped of the stack, active var still points to it. May I can manage this in backstack, but How can I found the which fragment active will have now?

Comment: The situation is very complicated. Maybe, you can create own active fragment stack. For example ; active fragment's tag add to arraylist. then you can use; active = fm.findFragmentByTag(arrayList.last())